# Need help in drawing google column stacked chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have a requirement to draw the column stacked chart as shown below .

Please help me on how i can draw the below graph and also let me know how to bring data from c# code to Jquery in order to draw chart in this fashion.

[Stacked Column Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttQ6i.png)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little broad, but I'll help you where I can.

If you want to export the data from C# server-side in a format friendly to the Google Visualization API, there's a tool called the Google DataTable .Net Wrapper.  I have an article about it on my blog here:

http://nicholasbering.ca/dot-net/2014/10/24/google-data-table-dot-net-wrapper/

Making a request from the client is another matter, and the details will depend a lot on how you are making it available from the server. If you are using JQuery to make the request, I suggest reading the JQuery documentation to learn how to do that.  I don't use JQuery for that myself, but I hear they have excellent docs.

To learn how to draw a stacked bar chart, check developers.google.com/chart, they also have excellent documentation, including an interactive example demonstrating the use of stacked bar charts.